# Selecting individual fields within a record

Tags: google-bigquery

To select the fields of a record I can do the following:

```
SELECT application_references FROM `patents-public-data.cpc.definition` 
where symbol='B03'
```

However, how would I select the fields within a struct, for example:

```
SELECT application_references.description, application_references.target FROM `patents-public-data.cpc.definition` 
where symbol='B03'
```

I tried using standard dot notation with an without tick marks, but wasn't able to select those inner fields. How would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT symbol, app_ref.description, app_ref.target 
FROM `patents-public-data.cpc.definition`, 
  UNNEST(application_references) app_ref 
WHERE symbol='A01D'
```

`application_references` is a repeated record so you have to unnest it first before referencing individual elements of array. after this you can use dot notation to access struct elements

If you want to see symbols that have empty application_references array - you can use LEFT JOIN as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT symbol, app_ref.description, app_ref.target 
FROM `patents-public-data.cpc.definition`
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(application_references) app_ref 
WHERE symbol='B03'
```